# Send std::stringstream in named pipe

Tags: c++

I have a variable of type std::stringstream where I write data in blob format, after which I want to send it to the pipe, from here the data is taken over by another application and sent via tcp socket. When I call std::stringstream.str() it shows me the correct information. If I give std::cout << std::stringstream.str().c_str() shows me empty result. I tried to send std::stringstream.str().c_str() to the pipe and get an empty space in the other application.

```
std::stringstream stream;
int fd;
const char* fifo = "/tmp/adpluspipe";

/* create the FIFO (named pipe) */
mkfifo(fifo, 0666);

/* write data to the FIFO */
fd = open(fifo, O_WRONLY);
write(fd, stream.str().data(), 84);
close(fd);

/* remove the FIFO */
unlink(fifo);
```

The content of the stream variable is the one in the image:
[content of the stream variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDTEF.png)

I receive a string of bytes through the socket, I decode that content according to the encryption documentation, I apply some filters and then I encode it only with the data I need. It has many areas with `'\0'` because in the end it must have the same length, so that when applying the decoding documentation it can work. The code is quite large and complex, so I couldn't display it. That encoded content looks like the one in the picture and I have to send it through a pipe to another application. I used `std::stringstream`, because here I was able to add byte by byte according to the encryption documentation.
The write code in that variable is:

```
// The data is added like this:
int value = std::bitset<8>("00111101").to_ulong();
// or
int value = 80;
// and so on



void writeBytes(std::stringstream &stream, int value, int valueSize)
{
    unsigned char bytes[valueSize];

    if(valueSize == 1){
        bytes[0] = value & 0xFF;
    }

    if(valueSize == 2){
        bytes[0] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
        bytes[1] = value & 0xFF;
    }

    if(valueSize == 4){
        bytes[0] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
        bytes[1] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
        bytes[2] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
        bytes[3] = value & 0xFF;
    }

    stream.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&bytes), sizeof(bytes));

    memset(bytes, 0, sizeof(bytes));

}
```

Comment: Please do not post links to images of text. Please post the text as text in your question. Is the content of stream variable the text that is showed in the image? Or does the image represent the resulting text from execution of `hexdump` or similar program when piped with the content of the stream variable?

Comment: You are not writing anything into the pipe and the reader should be the one making and destroying the fifo. If you unlink the fifo how is the writer supposed to read?

Comment: The image contains the contents of the stream variable. I want to send that content through pipe and then it can be decoded.  
If instead of that content I put a string in the stream variable and then send it through pipe, I can read that text without problems.

Comment: Please also have a [Minimal, Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without that, we often can't help you.

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
std::cout << std::stringstream.str().c_str();
```

it tries to interpret the data as a C string, and from the image, I can see that it clearly is not a C string, because it has null character `'\0'` in many places. Every C++ function that handles a C string will expect the string to be terminated by `'\0'`, so it stops processing the as soon as it sees the null character. That is not a problem when you use `std::string` (as returned by `.str()`) because it stores the size of the string, and does not rely on null character for a terminator. For a `std::string`, `'\0'` is not special.

As for why you can't see the contents on the receiving side, I can only speculate, since you haven't provided the code, but I would assume you are handling the data as a C string (`const char *`), no?

Comment: I have added more details below.
Thank you

Comment: @Cristian I've read the details you posted, but it is not clear to me what else can we help you with. I saw that you already use `stream.str().data()` to get the data, that should work, provided you used the correct size (b.t.w, you could use string's `.size()` for that).

Comment: Unfortunately both `stream.str().data ()` and `stream.str().c_str()` returns `null`, and does not send anything in the pipe. In `cout << stream.str()` returns the correct string and the others `null`.

Comment: Certainly the return value of `stream.str().data()` is not null, otherwise you'd get a segmentation fault. It is a pointer to the start of the buffer, and 84 bytes from that pointer are certainly written to the FIFO by `write()`. Why you can't receive it, as I said, I don't know because you have not shared the code. But Bailey Kocin comment might be right in that you erase the FIFO with `unlink()` before the receiving program has the chance to open it.

Comment: `write()` is not one of the functions that expects a C-string. Instead, it process the number of bytes you tell it to, in this case, 84. Doesn't matter if the value in the bytes is `'\0'` or not. On the other hand, `std::cout`'s `<<` do expects a C string when you feed it a `char *`, and will stop on the first `'\0'`.